# Spring @InitBinder for joda time

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jodatime

I have an initbinder for java.util.Date:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            Constants.DATE_PICTURE);
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
            dateFormat, true));
```

What can one use to bind a joda time LocalDateTime?
I'm using Spring 3.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use command objects, then a complete different, more elegant approach would be possible:using [`@DateTimeFormat`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) annotation.

```
public class CommandObject {
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a")
    public Date myDate();        
}

@Controller
public class ControllerClass{
   @RequestMapping("/myUrl")
   public ModelAndView(CommandObject c) {...}
}
```

(@See [this blog](http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/08/using-spring-3-datetimeformat.html#.UrHhuLSFe-U) for some example formatter)

Comment: There is no need for command objects. The annotation can be used in every thinkable way ;) + 1 for a solution without the obsolete PropertyEditor crap.

Comment: `@DateTimeFormat` supports Joda objects as well so +1.